# r generate indicator columns based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data-transform

Suppose this is my dataset

```
State     Enter Event  Lag 
State-A   2000  2004  -4 
State-A   2001  2004  -3
State-A   2002  2004  -2
State-A   2003  2004  -1
State-A   2004  2004   0
State-A   2005  2004   1
State-A   2006  2004   2
State-A   2007  2004   3
State-A   2008  2004   4
State-A   2009  2004   5
State-B   2000  2004  -5
State-B   2001  2004  -4
State-B   2002  2004  -3
State-B   2003  2004  -2
State-B   2004  2004  -1
State-B   2005  2004   0
State-B   2006  2004   1
State-B   2007  2004   2
State-B   2008  2004   3
State-B   2009  2004   4
```

My goal is the create several indicator columns based on the values in column `Lag` and **user defined Event window**.

If the user defined event window is between 2001 and 2008 then the expected dataset is to be like this

```
    State   Enter   Event   Lag LagM3_2001  LagM2_2002  LagM1_2003  Lead0_2004  Lead1_2005  Lead2_2006  Lead3_2007  Lead5_2008
   State-A  2000    2004    -4  1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
   State-A  2001    2004    -3  1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
   State-A  2002    2004    -2  0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
   State-A  2003    2004    -1  0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0
   State-A  2004    2004    0   0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0
   State-A  2005    2004    1   0           0           0           0           1           0           0           0
   State-A  2006    2004    2   0           0           0           0           0           1           0           0
   State-A  2007    2004    3   0           0           0           0           0           0           1           0    
   State-A  2008    2004    4   0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1
   State-A  2009    2004    5   0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1
   State-B  2000    2004    -4  1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
   State-B  2001    2004    -3  1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
   State-B  2002    2004    -2  0           1           0           0           0           0           0           0
   State-B  2003    2004    -1  0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0
   State-B  2004    2004    0   0           0           0           1           0           0           0           0
   State-B  2005    2004    1   0           0           0           0           1           0           0           0
   State-B  2006    2004    2   0           0           0           0           0           1           0           0
   State-B  2007    2004    3   0           0           0           0           0           0           1           0
   State-B  2008    2004    4   0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1
   State-B  2009    2004    5   0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1
```

Since the user defined event window is between 2001 and 2008.
First generate 2004 -2001 `(3 lag columns)`, 2008 - 2004 `(4 lead columns)`, 1 (Lead0) column .

Start with the lowest column which is `LagM3_2001`

- Any row where value in `Enter` column is `less or equal` to (2004-3)=2001 is assigned value 1
  So based on this logic, values in column `LagM3_2001` is 1 when `Enter` is 2001 or less(2000,1999) etc.

I will jump to the highest column which is `Lead5_2008`

- Any row where value in `Enter` column is `greater than or equal` to (2004+4)=2008 is assigned value 1
  So based on this logic, values in column `Lead5_2008` is 1 when `Enter` is 2008 or higher(2008,2009) etc.

This is the logic for any columns that are in between the lowest(`LagM3_2001`) and highest (`Lead5_2008`)

- Values in Column (`LagM2_2002`) is 1 if;  `2004-2 = 2002` & value in `Event` column is 2002, 0 everywhere else
- Values in Column (`LagM2_2003`) is 1 if;  `2004-1 = 2003` & value in `Event` column is 2001, 0 everywhere else
- Values in Column (`Lead0_2004`) is 1 if;  `2004-0 = 2004` & value in `Event` column is 2000, 0 everywhere else
- Values in Column (`Lead1_2005`) is 1 if;  `2004+1 = 2005` & value in `Event` column is 2005, 0 everywhere else
- Values in Column (`Lead1_2006`) is 1 if;  `2004+2 = 2006` & value in `Event` column is 2006, 0 everywhere else
- Values in Column (`Lead1_2007`) is 1 if;  `2004+3 = 2007` & value in `Event` column is 2007, 0 everywhere else

I could do this using lot of `ifelse` statements, but if there is an efficient way to code this, I would much appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: since all of the columns are mutually exclusive, have you considered just having one column with a factor?

Comment: @Mark, the design is predetermined and cannot be changed :)

Comment: okay bud, but I assume you have some sort of control over this. You're making your code harder to use + debug. Also, how is the user defining the event window?

Comment: also, in your first sample data, State-B's even is in 2005, and in the second, it's in 2004

Comment: @Mark, good question Mark, the event window is defined by the scientist. Fixed the error with State-B, not both State-A and B have events during 2004

Comment: how are they defining it? Through a function or something else?

Comment: @Mark, I believe based on economic factors, which I am not aware of.

Comment: I assumed that if the event was in 2005, then the lags would be 2001-2004, the event would be something else, and then leads would be 2005-2008

Comment: @Mark, in reality what you are describing is accurate, for now  I made this simple in this example, one event (2004) for all states.

Comment: in this, "*Since the user defined event window is between 2001 and 2008. First generate 2004 -2001 (3 lag columns), 2008 - 2004 (4 lead columns), 1 (Lead0) column .",* did you mean *"Since the user defined event window is between 2001 and 2008. First generate 2001 -2003 (3 lag columns), 2005 - 2008 (4 lead columns), 1 (Lead0) column (2004)*"?

Comment: @Mark, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, glue)

create_eventdf <- function(df, start, end) {
    df |>
    mutate(Category = case_when(Enter <= start ~ glue("LagM{Event-start}_{start}"),
                                Enter >= end ~ glue("Lead{Event-Enter+1}_{end}"),
                                Enter < Event ~ glue("LagM{Event-Enter}_{Enter}"),
                                TRUE ~ glue("Lead{Event-Enter+1}_{Event}")))|>
                                pivot_wider( names_from = Category, values_from = Category, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0, unused_fn = NULL)

}

create_eventdf(df, 2001, 2008)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 20 × 13
   State   Enter Event   Lag LagM3_2001 LagM2_2002 LagM1_2003 Lead1_2004
   <chr>   <int> <int> <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
 1 State-A  2000  2004    -4          1          0          0          0
 2 State-A  2001  2004    -3          1          0          0          0
 3 State-A  2002  2004    -2          0          1          0          0
 4 State-A  2003  2004    -1          0          0          1          0
 5 State-A  2004  2004     0          0          0          0          1
 6 State-A  2005  2004     1          0          0          0          0
 7 State-A  2006  2004     2          0          0          0          0
 8 State-A  2007  2004     3          0          0          0          0
 9 State-A  2008  2004     4          0          0          0          0
10 State-A  2009  2004     5          0          0          0          0
11 State-B  2000  2004    -5          1          0          0          0
12 State-B  2001  2004    -4          1          0          0          0
13 State-B  2002  2004    -3          0          1          0          0
14 State-B  2003  2004    -2          0          0          1          0
15 State-B  2004  2004    -1          0          0          0          1
16 State-B  2005  2004     0          0          0          0          0
17 State-B  2006  2004     1          0          0          0          0
18 State-B  2007  2004     2          0          0          0          0
19 State-B  2008  2004     3          0          0          0          0
20 State-B  2009  2004     4          0          0          0          0
# ℹ 5 more variables: Lead0_2004 <int>, `Lead-1_2004` <int>,
#   `Lead-2_2004` <int>, `Lead-3_2008` <int>, `Lead-4_2008` <int>
```

Comment: there is something wrong with the last lead column (`Lead5_2008`), I did some tweak and got it working. Thanks Mark.